# Adding strings with special characters within in SQL Server database by C# ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, string, special-characters

How can I add in a table with a column of type string (in SQL Server) an string like "jaja@yahoo.com" , I have problems with special character('@' in this case).Thanks

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(
                         "Data Source=BOGDAN-PC\\BOGDAN;Initial Catalog=ePlanning;Integrated Security=SSPI;Connect Timeout=10;TrustServerCertificate=True ");
                string[] id_dep = ddDepartament.SelectedItem.Text.Split('.');
                con.Open();



                string final = tbemailangajat.Text.

                string sqlstring = " Update angajati set nume='" + tbNumeangajat.Text + "' ,prenume= '" + tbPrenumeangajat.Text + "',email= '" + final + "',telefon= '" + tbTelefonAngajat.Text + "',id_functie= " + ddFunctieAngajat.SelectedItem.Text[0].ToString() + ",id_departament= " + ddDepartament.SelectedItem.Text[0].ToString() + " where id_angajat = " + int.Parse(tbID.Text) + ";";
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand comm = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(sqlstring, con);
                //  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader reader;
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Comment: post your C# code. and also Error

Comment: I already made my table with an column named Email, and the type is varchar(50), and when I try to add a row with a string of like "me@yahoo.com" for the column Email, the row is nod added

Comment: that's does not describe your problem enough. Was there an error? Where is your code?

Comment: show the code where you try to add the row, so we can help

Comment: code provided, no error is displayed, just the row in not added

Comment: The code that you provided a) does not compile (due to the line `string final = tbemailangajat.Text.`- maybe that should be `string final = tbemailangajat.Text;`?) b) Performs an update, not an insert.  If you expect a new row to be inserted, you need to execute an insert statement instead.  Otherwise, the problem may be that no rows match the `where` clause that you provided.

Comment: `final` is a keyword. mind if you change that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't use sql injection, use parameterized queries instead.

```
command.CommandText = "insert into table (column) values(@p1)";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("p1", "email@address.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

varchar should allow for the @ symbol, but for some symbols it requires nvarchar instead of varchar.  nvarchar stores unicode and is used to support symbols outside of the ASCII range.

Comment: so I have to drop my table and built it again,that's the only way now?

Comment: If you are going to support international charachters you will probably have to recreate the table (or set the option to let the manager do it for you).  I agree that parameterizing your query is best, but looking at your query, it should allow you to insert the @ symbol.

Comment: The option to allow the tool to recreate the table when you change the field type in Management Studio is Tools > Options > Designers and then uncheck the following option "Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation"

Comment: can't find designers option, hmmm